# How to Combine 2 Result (add Column) from Linq Select into 1 Table or CrossJoin in ASP.Net Core

Tags: mysql, linq, asp.net-core

Greatings,

I Have 1 table and want to Show 1 table with different where parameters.
The Table Will show an **Item** and The **TodaySales** and **Until Today Sales**

I only know to get Today Sales with doing like this

```
var result = (from Sales in _context.Sales
                          where Sales.ShipmentDate == dates
                          group Sales by new { cat = Sales.ItemCategoryCode } into res
                          select new { ProductGroup = res.Key.cat, amount = res.Sum(a => a.Qty) }).ToList();
            return Ok(result);
```

and for the 2nd I doing like this

```
var result2 = (from Sales in _context.Sales
                          where Sales.ShipmentDate.Value.Year == dates.Year
                          && Sales.ShipmentDate.Value.Month == dates.Month
                          && Sales.ShipmentDate.Value.Date <= dates.Date
                          group Sales by new { cat = Sales.ItemCategoryCode } into res
                          select new { ProductGroup = res.Key.cat, amount = res.Sum(a => a.Qty) }).ToList();
            return Ok(result2);
```

Maybe someone can tell me the best Linq Query for that, or can help me to merge the result.

ThankYou

Comment: Please amend your question to include the definitions of your tables as well.

Comment: Have you considered to use Linq's [Union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union) extension method? It does work if the columns are matching.

Comment: @PeterCsala sorry, I'm very new in Linq. I will try that union method

Comment: All you need is this: `return Ok(result.Union(result2));` Or in the other way around if  `result2`'s items should come first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work:

```cs
var query = 
   from Sales in _context.Sales
   group Sales by new { cat = Sales.ItemCategoryCode } into res
   select new 
   { 
       ProductGroup = res.Key.cat, 
       TodaySales = res.Sum(a => a.ShipmentDate == dates ? a.Qty : 0),
       UntilTodaySales = res.Sum(a => a.ShipmentDate.Value.Year == dates.Year
                          && a.ShipmentDate.Value.Month == dates.Month
                          && a.ShipmentDate.Value.Date <= dates.Date ? a.Qty : 0)
   };
```